# Will upgrading to a newer version delete my files, apps, or settings?

Tags: upgrade

I am planning to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10?

Does upgrading delete my files, documents and third party apps. Or does it keep my files and documents but deletes third party apps??

Answer (score 3):

You should always backup your personal files even when not upgrading. Better safe than sorry.

Upgrading normally does not delete files. If needed upgrading will disable 3rd party applications (and not delete them).